# SIGTSTP kills background process

Tags: c++, shell, unix, process, signals

I am programming my own unix shell. When I try something like `firefox&` my new child process is starting/running in background.
But when I hit `CTRL-C` in the mother process (my shell) it closes firefox (my background(-child)process). I don´t want to close the bg child process with `CTRL-C`. It should do nothing (it should only kill the fg process, if there is one other than my shell).

I´ve read about `WIFEXITED(status)` but I don't really know how to work with it.

My signal handler:

```cpp
void signal_handler(int signum) {
    switch (signum) {
        case SIGINT:                                // CTRL-C
            cout << " [caught SIGINT]" << pid << endl;
            if(pid != 0) {
                kill(pid, SIGINT);
            }
            break;
        case SIGTSTP:                               // CTRL-Z
            cout << " [caught SIGTSTP]" << endl;
            if(pid != 0) {
                kill(pid, SIGTSTP);
            }
            break;
        case SIGCHLD:
            while((waitpid(pid,0, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED))>0) {
                cout << "[" << pid << "] done" << endl;
            } 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

And this is how I start a process:

```cpp
// some names of variables were changed to show it to you more readable.

signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
signal(SIGCHLD, signal_handler);

if (input == "fg" || input == "bg") {
        if (input == "fg") {
            pid = inputPid(input);                  //function to get pid when user types something like fg 1234 (foreground pid 1234)
            kill(pid, SIGCONT);                     // SIGCONT -> continue
            cout << "[" << inputPid(input) << "]" << endl;
            waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);       // WUNTRACED -> return if a child has stopped
            pid = 0;
        } else if (input == "bg") {
            bgPids.push_back(pid);
            kill(pid,SIGCONT);
        }
    } else if(input == "background") {
        cout << "PIDs in Background: ";
        for(int i = 0; i < bgPids.size(); i++) {    // vector which gets all background pids
            cout << "[" << bgPids[i] << "] ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } else {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {                      // child

            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);    
            signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
            signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
            setpgid(0, getpid());               
            execvp(arguments[0], &arguments[0]);
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            exit(1);
        } else if (checkIfBackground(inputNew) == false) {  // mother
            pid_t pid_r;
            if (waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED) < 0) {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
            }
        } else { // when user types argument& or argument &
            bgPids.push_back(pid);
            cout << "Prozess is in background!" << endl;
            if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
                cout << "bg exited" << status << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your signal handler, what process does `pid` refer to? You can't send any signals on to the child process if it's running "in the background".

Comment: When I type `bg` it is the pid of the most actual process. So when I type `firefox` -> `CTRL-Z` -> `bg` pid is the pid of `firefox`-process. When I type `firefox` -> `CTRL-Z` -> `ps ax` -> `fg (here the pid of firefox)` pid is not the id of the newest process (in this case it would be `ps ax`), but it´s the pid of `firefox` now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg could you please tell me what you've edited? Thank you.

Comment: If you click on the link "edited X mins ago" you can see the changes made.

Comment: I can't see any changes in the code. Did you change anything?

Comment: No, I only added the C++ language tag and some formatting hints. I would never edit code. If I wanted to show some code I would have added an answer.

Comment: Normally you should not have to manage SIGINT nor SIGTSTP propagation by yourself, you have to play with process groups and controlling terminal foreground process group (see `tcsetpgrp`).